# spring mvc: convert json property in DTO to Enum

Tags: json, spring-mvc, unmarshalling

I'd like to have a String sent from the client to be converted to its respective Enum value.

Given:

```
public enum TheEnum {
    One,
    Two
}
```

when hitting `bindsToParams?boolVal=false&stringVal=foobar&enumVal=one`

```
@Controller
//..
public void bindsToParams(
    @RequestParam Boolean boolVal,
    @RequestParam String stringVal,
    @RequestParam TheEnum enumVal) {
        // this works. enumVal created correctly
}
```

I'd like the same enum conversion to happen, when the enum is a property of a DTO, and the incoming payload is json. So, with the following DTO:

```
public BagOfProps {
    Boolean boolVal;
    String stringVal;
    TheEnum enumVal;
}
```

When sending: `{"boolVal":false,"stringVal":"foobar",enumVal: "One"}`

```
@Controller
//..
public void bindsToObject(
    @RequestBody BagOfProps bag) {
        // unmarshalling of boolVal, stringVal works
        // but bag.enumVal is null
}
```

What should I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

Deserialising the nested enum actually works out of the box. Reason it didn't work for me was that in the json payload, the name of the enum property was different than the name of the variable in the DTO:

I was sending:

```
{"boolVal":false,"stringVal":"foobar",enumVal: "One"}
```

While the DTO was in-fact:

```
public BagOfProps {
    Boolean boolVal;
    String stringVal;
    TheEnum notTheSameNameAsEnumVal;
}
```

HTH